# How do i make this close between header and nav? Why is it separated space between header and topnav?

Tags: html

can you please help us solve this code about the problem? how do you make this close between something like this? [unwanted space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuVLe.jpg)

Comment: Show code. What you did so far?

Comment: By modifying the HTML and/or CSS.

Comment: Probably, could you give some actual code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin to adjust the space between two container.

here I used `margin-top: -5px` to close the gap between two img

***check this example:***

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/uxyLh8yp/

if you can post your html/css code it will be better.